# Add the Terraform Summary as a Github PR comment from Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, github, azure-devops, terraform, pull-request

Our organization uses Github and Azure DevOps for CI/CD purposes. I'm trying to automate infrastructure deployment using Terraform. The pipeline is triggered whenever a PR is raised. During the terraform deployment using Azure DevOps, I want the build pipeline to add a comment to the PR. **The PR should be the `terraform plan` summary for the application owner to review.**

I am using the following code but for some reason, the task does not post the content of the variable. The comment just reads `$(terraformOutput)`.

Am I missing something here or is there any documentation/blog I could follow to accomplish this task?

```
    - task: AzureCLI@2
      displayName: 'Terraform Init and Plan'
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: <....>
        scriptType: 'bash'
        scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
        inlineScript: |
          export ARM_CLIENT_ID=$servicePrincipalId
          export ARM_CLIENT_SECRET=$servicePrincipalKey
          export ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID=$(az account show --query id | xargs)
          export ARM_TENANT_ID=$(az account show --query tenantId | xargs)
          
          terraform init -reconfigure -backend-config=storage_account_name=<...> -backend-config=container_name=<..> -backend-config=key=<..> -backend-config=resource_group_name=<...>

          terraform workspace select prod || terraform workspace new prod
          terraform validate
          terraform plan -var-file=dummy.tfvars -no-color -out=tfplan
          terraform show -json terraform.plan > terraform.json
        addSpnToEnvironment: true
        workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
        failOnStandardError: true

    - powershell: |
        $terraformOutput = Get-Content "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/terraform.json" | ConvertFrom-Json
        
      name: terraformOutput
      displayName: Read terraform outputs

    - task: GitHubComment@0
      inputs:
        gitHubConnection: 'post-pr-comment'
        repositoryName: '$(Build.Repository.Name)'
        comment: '$(terraformOutput)'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass variable like this. You need to create a [azure pipeline variable via logging command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=powershell) as follow:

```yaml
    - powershell: |
        $terraformOutput = Get-Content "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/terraform.json" | ConvertFrom-Json
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar;]$terraformOutput"
      name: terraformOutput
      displayName: Read terraform outputs

    - task: GitHubComment@0
      inputs:
        gitHubConnection: 'post-pr-comment'
        repositoryName: '$(Build.Repository.Name)'
        comment: '$(testvar)'
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem that the comment can't accept the multiline string from the variable you have, so you need to change the format for your results and make it as a variable and use this variable for GH PR comment like this:

```
COMMENT=$(cat "${SYSTEM_DEFAULTWORKINGDIRECTORY}/plan.txt" | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/%0D%0A/g' |sed 's/\x1b\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z]//g')
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable= COMMENT;]$COMMENT"
```

After that for the GH comment:

```
  - task: GitHubComment@0
    condition: succeeded()
    inputs:
      gitHubConnection: 'Securrency'
      repositoryName: '$(Build.Repository.Name)'
      comment: |
        Terragrunt plan command for the modules changed is succeed and the result is: 
        $(COMMENT)
```